# How Skype "protects" its password in keychain on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, security, password-protection, keychain, skype

When I open skype entry on keychain, and try to set Show Password checkbox, password is not shown, checkbox becomes unchecked.
This behavior described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12785477#12785477) and [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1016717).
If I run

```
security find-generic-password -ga .token.0
```

from Terminal App , in line password I see 
long 48-digit hexadecimal number and string, like this:

```
password: 0xAABAAA1AAA4AA5AAAAA6AAA3F6AACAACAAA77AAAAAAAAAAA  "\245\241\240...".
```

If I run this terminal command for any other keychain entry, where I can see password through checking checkbox in Keychain App, it prints readable passowrd on this line.
I tried to get password programmatically using SSKeychain class, and I get nil.

What API/technology Skype uses for such protection of its password?
I want to use this technique in my app to protect my passwords.